# How to add hundreds of image data using realm with swift

Tags: swift, database, realm

I am new on Realm and a little bit experience with swift here. I am trying to write programming myself. I want to save image data and some information about this image in my database which is base on realm. I woundering if I have to add each picture one by one like this:

```
    func loadimageData(){
    if itemimageResult!.count > 0 {
        return
    }
    let imageURL1 = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "ShakerColor1", withExtension: "png")!
    let imageURL2 = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "ShakerColor2", withExtension: "png")!
    let imageURL3 = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "ShakerColor3", withExtension: "png")!
    let imageData1 = try! Data(contentsOf: imageURL1)
    let imageData2 = try! Data(contentsOf: imageURL2)
    let imageData3 = try! Data(contentsOf: imageURL3)
    let putImage1 = itemImage(value:[2,imageData1])
    let putImage2 = itemImage(value:[2,imageData2])
    let putImage3 = itemImage(value:[2,imageData3])
    try! realm.write{
        realm.add(putImage1)
        realm.add(putImage2)
        realm.add(putImage3)
    }
}
```

I want to know if there is any other better way of doing it.

Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: Do you know the number of images or names of those images that need to be added to the database beforehand?

Comment: I can rename them. My problem is that I also need to store related data to image for example if this picture is a CAT, it need to store "cateName","catBrade","catSex" . I do know how many picture I need to add.

Comment: If you know the number of images that you need to add beforehand, then you can create a **struct** and define needed properties and store the data in an array. Then you loop through the array to add all the records to your database.

Comment: That code will definitely work and is the correct structure for writing data to Realm. The first concern though, is you're reading the images from your bundle. Is it your intention of storing them in that fashion? If so, why have them available in the bundle but also write them to realm (which is a duplicate)? Also, we don't know what `itemImage(value:[2,imageData1])` does so that should be explained. Is `itemImage` a class?

Comment: Yes, itemImage is a class. if I don't store them in bundle where should I read those image from? I am kind know to this.

Comment: You're getting them from your bundle with this `Bundle.main.url(forResource: "ShakerColor1", withExtension: "png"` Its not a question of where you should read them from, it's a question of where do you *want* to read them from.

Answer (score 0):

This is an answer but not the only answer. If you have a list of images and you want to write them to realm, here's what I would do.

Start with a class that stores the image data. You could optionally add maybe an image title, or what the image is about etc.

```
class ImageClass: Object {
    @objc dynamic var imageData: Data?

    convenience init(withImageName: String) {
        self.init()
        let imageUrl = Bundle.main.url(forResource: withImageName, withExtension: "png")!
        let imageData = try! Data(contentsOf: imageUrl)
        self.imageData = imageData
    }
}
```

Then a list of the image names. I don't know how yours are stored but I have them in an array and they are stored in the app bundle.

```
let imageNames = [ "ShakerColor1", "ShakerColor2", "ShakerColor3" ]
```

Then code to build an array of ImageClasses

```
   let images = imageNames.map { name -> ImageClass in
      let image = ImageClass(withImageName: name)
      return image
   }
```

and then finally write the images to Realm.

```
do {
    let realm = try Realm()

    try! realm.write {
        realm.add(images)
    }

} catch let error as NSError {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

Comment: thank you very much for the suggestion I will try it out